# Sage math numerical evaluation

Tags: sage

I'm using Sage math to do some calculation where I found the numerical evaluation quite different from that of python's.

For example, the evalf() nolonger works, instead it uses n() and gp().

My questions are:

1. what are different ways of numerical evaluation in Sage and what's their difference?
2. what's difference between n() and gp()? why the later seemed to be much slower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Sympy when you say `evalf`.  Anyway, `n()` or `numerical_approx()` is the equivalent.  See [the documentation](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLK81NLcpMTsyJTywoKMqvsAcAP9gG-Q==&lang=sage).  The default is 53 bits of accuracy.

You shouldn't be thinking of `gp()` though, unless you really want to use the [GP/Pari](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr) interpreter or convert something to GP.

Comment: What's so different about gp()? Does it provide more accuracy or speed?  The explantation on the webpages says "gp is an easy-to-use interactive shell giving access to the PARI functions." But from the sage software, the gp() response much slower than the n() function.

Comment: Well, the point is that Pari is a completely different program inside of Sage!  It is mainly for number theory - which does sometimes need quite accurate approximations of real numbers e.g. if you want to calculate L-function values - but it is not something you should use just to get 1000 digits of pi.